# Calling a remote ejb on a different glassfish 4.0 instance

Tags: ejb, glassfish-4

I have two servers installed. Both are running an own Glassfish 4.0 domain.

On one server, I've installed an Singleton Remote EJB. This Glassfish has an IIOP-Listener specified (name=UF enabled=true network adress=192.168.10.95 listener port=1072).

The second Glassfish instance is running a simple JSF-2.2 Application.
Now I'm trying to connect to the remote ejb in one JSF-Managed-Bean constructor.

```java
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://192.168.10.95:1072");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.10.95");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "1072");
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        return (IUF) ctx.lookup("java:global/UFRemote/UFRemote!com.uf.IUF");
```

The lookup took about one minute and ends up with following exception:

```
SEVERE:   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/UFRemote/UFRemote!uf.IUserFramework' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=1072, java.naming.provider.url=iiop://192.168.10.95:1072, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.10.95, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=1072, java.naming.provider.url=iiop://192.168.10.95:1072, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.10.95, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.10.95; port: 1072  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at uf.UF.lookupIUserFramework(UF.java:47)
at uf.UF.<clinit>(UF.java:17)
at beans.TestBean.<init>(TestBean.java:22)
at beans.TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:262)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyFactory.create(ClientProxyFactory.java:103)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:157)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:147)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:49)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:57)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:358)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:396)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:163)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=1072, java.naming.provider.url=iiop://192.168.10.95:1072, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.10.95, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.10.95; port: 1072  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:334)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
... 86 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: 00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 192.168.10.95; port: 1072  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy214.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ContactInfoImpl.createConnection(ContactInfoImpl.java:129)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:243)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.request(ClientDelegateImpl.java:227)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.is_a(ClientDelegateImpl.java:392)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext$ProviderCacheKey.getNameService(SerialContext.java:1205)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:393)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:344)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:250)
... 97 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:364)
```

I think, something is wrong with the connection, because everything works fine, if I deploy both on the same Glassfish instance.

How do I call a remote EJB correctly from a different Glassfish domain?

Comment: If it takes one minute, check these items: Correct IP address? Correct port? Is the server *really* listening on *all* interfaces (= not only on localhost)? Is there a firewall/packet filter in between?

Answer (score 2):

**1) IP Addressing**

Try to set org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost to the network host-name instead the ip address.
Make sure that the client can reach the server by host-name (ping host-name), if necessary edit hosts table (**linux**: etc/hosts **windows**: c:\windows\system32\drivers\hosts) and add a line with:

'ip' 'host-name' (Example 192.168.1.1 server1)

(Even after you solve the naming issue, problems can appear because of direct ip addressing  )

**2) Accessing EJB Components in a Remote GlassFish Server**

In addition to the ip issue, make sure that the server as declared the JDNI resource. See text bellow from Glassfish Application-development-guide Manual:

The recommended approach for looking up an EJB component in a remote GlassFish
Server from a client that is a servlet or EJB component is to use the Interoperable
Naming Service syntax. Host and port information is prepended to any global JNDI
names and is automatically resolved during the lookup. The syntax for an
interoperable global name is as follows:

```
corbaname:iiop:host:port#a/b/name
```

This makes the programming model for accessing EJB components in another
GlassFish Server exactly the same as accessing them in the same server. The deployer
can change the way the EJB components are physically distributed without having to
change the code.

For Java EE components, the code still performs a `java:comp/env` lookup on an EJB
reference. The only difference is that the deployer maps the ejb-ref element to an
interoperable name in a GlassFish Server deployment descriptor file instead of to a
simple global JNDI name.

For example, suppose a servlet looks up an EJB reference using
`java:comp/env/ejb/Foo`, and the target EJB component has a global JNDI name of
`a/b/Foo`.

The ejb-ref element in **glassfish-web.xml** looks like this:

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Foo</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:host:port#a/b/Foo</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

**The code looks like this:**

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
Object o = ic.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Foo");
```

**For a client that doesn't run within a Java EE container, the code just uses the
interoperable global name instead of the simple global JNDI name. For example:**

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
Object o = ic.lookup("corbaname:iiop:host:port#a/b/Foo");
```

Objects stored in the interoperable naming context and component-specific
(java:comp/env) naming contexts are transient. On each server startup or application
reloading, all relevant objects are re-bound to the namespace.

(GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 Application Development Guide)

Comment: In Glassfish, how is `corbaname` defined?  Is this an IIOP listener?  Or a JNDI resource?